# Open a razor page from JS with long url

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-2.2

Using ASP.NET Core 2.2 with razor pages... I have a razor page1 which includes a table with lots of integer Id-values from a database. I have to open another razor page via JavaScript and pass all the Ids from page1 to page2. At the moment I do it like this:

```
window.location.href = "/myUrl/page2?idList=..."
```

and pass the list of Ids as a JSON-string. This works well until the URL becomes too long (the string for idList becomes too long).

What I need to know: how can I pass a long list of integer values to a razor page via JavaScript without getting in the limit with the URL?

TIA
Heiko

Comment: You shouldn't have to pass all those IDs in the first place I guess? What if you pass some type of information instead that allows the next page to read the relevant values from the DB instead? Anyway, if you really must do this, the answer is to simulate a form submission. Create a `<form method="post" action="/myUrl/page2">`, append a hidden input containing the list as value with `name="iDList"`, then submit the form by calling `submit()` on it. The server must process a POST param instead of a GET param, obviously. (but again, this is a bad workaround for what's most likely an xy problem)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the workaround is a start. The problem is: I have a grid-component where the user can filter a list of data. Than I have to get all Ids from user selection an pass it to another page.

Comment: Hi @okieh, "I have a grid-component where the user can filter a list of data. Than I have to get all Ids from user selection an pass it to another page." Do you mean you have to submit the selected Ids to the server side, and filter data based on the Ids? If that is the case, as Chris said, you could submit the a `<form>` and use a hidden filed to store the Ids, or you could use jQuery Ajax (Post) method. If you just want to share the Ids on the client sides, you could use cookies to store the Ids.

Comment: I finally implemented the solution with the form and it works! Setting cookies is difficult because of restrictions.